# Проблема с выводом элемента массива из файла

Tags: c++, c, файлы, winapi

Возникла проблема с выводом максимального элемента из массива в файле. Вместо элемента, мне выводит адрес. Не понимаю, в чём может быть проблема.
Содержимое файла:

```
3
7
4
1
7
9
10
```

Выводит:

```
956960055
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Папка\\file.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    HANDLE hMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);

    int* pData = (int*)MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
    int nElements = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL) / sizeof(int);

    int maxNumber = pData[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < nElements; i++)
    {
        if (pData[i] > maxNumber)
        {
            maxNumber = pData[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "Максимальное число в массиве: " << maxNumber << endl;

    UnmapViewOfFile(pData);
    CloseHandle(hMapping);
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не адрес. Если расписать 956960055 в виде 4-байтного числа в 16-ричной системе, то получим 390A0D37 — т.е. исходя из little-endian, это символ 7, перевод строки (`"\r\n"`) и 9 - ничего из вашего файла не напоминает?

```
7
9
```

Ваша проблема в том, что вы к *текстовым данным* обращаетесь как к *бинарным*.